# Quickblox: Cannot get users by tag_list. Error: Token is required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quickblox

I need to get the users that have been put into a specific room. The room name is entered at log in into the tag_list parameter. I adjusted the example's code to get the users by the tag_list parameter but it says I need a token to get access. Can anyone explain what is happening in the example code that I have not replicated? Here is my code:

```
$scope.callees = [$scope.user.id];
$scope.sessionType = QB.webrtc.CallType.VIDEO; // AUDIO is also possible
$scope.session = QB.webrtc.createNewSession($scope.callees, $scope.sessionType);
var mediaParams = {
    audio: true,
    video: true,
    options: {
        muted: true,
        mirror: true
    },
    elemId: 'localVideoEl',
    optional: {
        minWidth: 240,
        maxWidth: 320,
        minHeight: 160,
        maxHeight: 240
    }
};

QB.users.get(
    {
        'tags': [$scope.user.tag_list], 
        'per_page': 100
    }, 
function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Angular users... Turns out the answer is SO EXCITING!!! (sarcasm) It turns out You have to wrap the request in yet another QB.login and yet another QB.createSession...

```
QB.createSession(function(err,result){
    if (result) {
        QB.login($scope.user, function(loginErr, loginUser){
            if (loginErr) {
                console.log('log in error');
                console.log(loginErr);
            }else {

// HANDLE USERS                     

                var params = {tags: [$scope.user.tag_list]};
                QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });

// HANDLE CHAT  

                QB.chat.connect(patient, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); } else { console.log(res); }
                });

// HANDLE VIDEO 

                $scope.callees = [$scope.user.id];
                $scope.sessionType = QB.webrtc.CallType.VIDEO; // AUDIO is also possible
                $scope.session = QB.webrtc.createNewSession($scope.callees, $scope.sessionType);

                var mediaParams = {
                    audio: true,
                    video: true,
                    options: {
                        muted: true,
                        mirror: true
                    },
                    elemId: 'localVideoEl',
                    optional: {
                        minWidth: 240,
                        maxWidth: 320,
                        minHeight: 160,
                        maxHeight: 240
                    }
                };
                $scope.session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function(err, stream) {
                    if (err){
                        //console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        //console.log(stream);
                    }
                });




            }
        });
    }else if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

So it appears despite all the efforts to have a single page app you still have to log in on every page... If anyone in the Angular community has a better answer to continuously logging in after every route change I would be not sarcastically delighted! Feel free to list your solution and I will mark it correct instead of mine... as mine, I feel, is not the real answer...

Comment: That's because you have to create QB.createSession and obtain the session token in order to use QB API. Otherwise you will be getting 'token is required'